# Exclude sub directory from static files in express

Tags: node.js, express

Is there any way to **exclude** sub directory from express static middleware in **express** 4.8.5.

For example if I have :

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + 'public'));
```

And my public directory is like this :

```
- public  
   - css
   - images
   - scripts
   - index.html
   - exclude_me
        - scripts
        - views
        - index.html
```

So I need to exclude last sub directory and when user does :

```
GET /exclude_me
```

It should call my route rather than returning directory automatically.

I can't just remove it from public dir because it depends on stuff inside it because **public** directory is angular application and **exclude_me** is another angular application that fetches scripts from **/exclude_me/scripts** **AND** from **/public/scripts**.

I know it is little confusing but it is how it is and I cannot just remove it from public dir because it won't see **public/scripts** any more which are needed and I cannot leave it because I cannot authorize it then (all authorization is in **public/scripts**)

If there is some smarter way to do this, feel free to let me know :)

Comment: What do you mean stuff inside depends on it?

Comment: I've added additional information in question

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can add your own middleware. Here's what I did to exclude some folders:

```
app.use('/public', (req, res, next) => {
  if (env !== 'development') {
    var result = req.url.match(/^\/js\/(maps|src)\/.+\.js$/)
    if (result) {
      return res.status(403).end('403 Forbidden')
    }
  }
  next()
})
app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')))
```

Answer (score 16):

It's possible by adding regular expressions to the first optional param of `use` method.

According with [Express 4.x API path documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#path-examples).

Example, I don't want to give access to my `secure` folder inside `public` folder:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use([/^\/public\/secure($|\/)/, '/public'], express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

This will allow you to access all files but not the ones in the `secure` folder.

You can use it also to restrict a file extension, example files that ends with `.js.map`:

```
app.use([/(.*)\.js\.map$/, '/public'], express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

And you also can add multiple rules, like this example where `secure` folder and files that end with `.js.map` are ignored from the static folder:

```
app.use([/^\/public\/secure($|\/)/, /(.*)\.js\.map$/, '/public'], express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Comment: This answer looks more efficient than the accepted answer

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem, which may be the answer you were seeking. Given the following directory:

```
public
   css/
   images/
   secure/
   index.html
```

The Express Middleware stack I wanted was this:

```
1. Static files (except the `secure/` directory)
2. Logging
3. Authentication
4. `secure/` static files
```

Here's how I solved it:

```
var express = require('express');

var path = require('path');
var app = express();

// path.join here makes it work cross platform with Windows / Linux / etc
var statics = express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'));

function secureStatic(secure) {
  return function (req, res, next) {
    if (/^\/secure/.test(req.path) === !!secure) return statics(req, res, next);

    return next();
  };
}

// add public files
app.use(secureStatic());
app.use(logging());
app.use(authentication());

// add secured files
app.use(secureStatic(true));
```

This will only serve public files when unauthenticated, and only serve secure files after authentication.

Answer (score 2):

Most solutions above are to use a middleware.

However, there is a just easier way to solve this.

Don't serve static assests directly with the dir `public` rather than serve dir just what you want to serve with a virtual path prefix .

You can serve like below

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use('/public', __dirname + 'css');
app.use('/public', __dirname + 'images');
...
```

Comment: Underrated answer

Comment: it is recommended to keep css, js and images in separate directories. so it's better to use `/public/css` and `/public/images` mappings