# Express file serving only requested from index.html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, express

Is there any way I could serve index.html in Express through a get request and send all the external files the index.html requested?

For example, here's a very simple index.html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    </head>
</html>
```

Now, `app.get('/', function (req, res) {res.sendFile('index.html')}` would send the index.html but the jquery.js would not be sent. Is there anyway I could solve this and allow all external files index.html requested to be sent as well? I know I could use `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));` although I don't want the user to access some files in the public folder.

Comment: Separate the anonymous and protected documents and serve them appropriately.  You already have working code - just write the erst

Comment: @akaphenom I still want it in the public directory

Comment: so those middlewares essentially adds a point where it searches those directories for files, and should it not find an exact match returns it to the next function in the middleware.  It might provide the ability to customize / configure the search (I don't remember). Alternatively you could look at that code and write your own version of it - it should be pretty simple.

Answer (score 0):

Put you library files in the same folder that you're exposing via the static files middleware.

For instance I have my client files including `index.html` in a folder called `wwwroot`. Inside of the folder I have a folder `lib` where all of my dependencies go, thus my `index.html` will be referencing the files from `lib`,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="lib/jquery.js"></script>
    </head>
</html>
```

And of course expose `wwwroot` via static files middleware, `app.use(express.static('./wwwroot', options));`.

And if you don't want some of the files to be accessed publicly either remove them as [rsp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/613198/rsp) mentioned from that folder or try to use options,

```
let options = {
    dotfiles: 'ignore',
    etag: false,
    extensions: ['html', 'ts', 'css', 'js']
}
```

Comment: How do I stop app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))); from accessing a folder

Comment: The point of app.use(express.static()) is to expose the folder. Do you mean how prevent access to a folder inside of `public`?

Comment: Yeah, that' what I mean.

Comment: Have you looked at other stackoverflow threads? For instance your questions has already been discussed here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28680738/exclude-sub-directory-from-static-files-in-express](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28680738/exclude-sub-directory-from-static-files-in-express)

Comment: Yeah I was just looking at that one except I don't know how the url matching thing works

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want the user to access some files in the public folder.

If you don't want the user to access some files in the public folder then you should remove those files from the public folder.

But if you remove those files from the public folder then don't expect that they can be served to the client.

You can check if a request was a result of accessing index.html like checking the Referer header or remembering that a user accessed index.html a second ago but everything will be easy co circumvent.

Every file that can be accessed as a result of being included in index.html can also be downloaded by the user. This is how the Web works and there is no way around it.