# ExpressJS: Having problems combining wildcard-routing and rendering with EJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express, ejs

I'm developing an Angular 4.x application, that contains its own internal routing. 
It will run on an Express server, which unfortunately has its own routing that overrides the one in the Angular app.
I was initially trying to solve this by using wildcard routing on the Express server, but it leads to other problems.

Part of this is also related to using EJS for template rendering.
I will explain in steps.

First of all, we have the following routes:

```
/ (root)
/appartment
/apartment/:id
/student
/student/:id
```

The following is the index.html file that is rendered and returned:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>

    <%- headerMenu %>

    <app-root></app-root>

    <%- footer %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Since it's an Angular application with its own internal routing, only the index.html file will be returned from the server, and it should be returned for all paths.

As you can see, there are some EJS template tags.
Our real application is part of a larger website, so for this particular application we're using EJS to inject the same headerMenu and footer content that is found on all our pages.
The various web pages/applications are made with different frameworks over the years, and this one is using Angular 4.x, hosted on an Express server.

Below is a working version of our js-file:

```
var path = require("path");
var express = require("express");
var ejs = require("ejs");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var http = require('http');

//....... All other content here .... 
//....... All other content here .... 
//....... All other content here .... 

var app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.engine('html', ejs.renderFile);
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get(['/', '/apartment(/:id)?', '/student(/:id)?'], function(req, res) {
    res.render('../dist/index.html', {
        headerMenu: ourWebContent.headerMenu,
        footer: ourWebContent.foooter
    });
});

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/dist')));

app.listen(env.port, function () {
    console.log('server running at ' + env.port + ', go refresh and see magic');
});
```

The properties env.port and ourWebContent were defined before this code section.

As you can see, every route used in the Angular app is stated explicitly in the Express server code as well:

```
['/', '/apartment(/:id)?', '/student(/:id)?']
```

Unfortunately, by this approach, for each new route I introduce in the Angular application, I'll have to add them in Express as well.

I've tried wildcard routing, something like this:

```
['/', '/*']
```

It should have worked, but in my application it causes the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

Now, some of you may have noticed the following code stated **below** the route:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/dist')));
```

This is where the compiled index.html is stored.
After googling the error, although I don't remember where I found the solution (somewhere else on Stackoverflow) and the exact explanation behind, it seems to be working if I move this particular code line before the routing.

Unfortunately, it introduces a new problem: EJS won't render most of the time.
What I end up seeing is unrendered text, instead of the headerMenu and the footer.

So the question: How can I fix the wildcard routing, without breaking the EJS rendering?

Comment: Have you thought about location hash strategy? - https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/routing/routing-strategies/#_hashlocationstrategy -- That will only need support for the `/` path and then the client router handles the rest of the url

Comment: I would move index.html outta dist, one level up

Answer (score 0):

What you should do (at least what I do) to avoid such conflicts is to add a prefix to your express API.
So, your express application will return the index.ejs (or whatever extension) when you make a request to `/`

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index');
});
```

Now, if you have an API for appartments, then it goes like so:

```
app.use('/api/appartments', require('routes/appartments'));

//inside routes/appartments.js
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  return res.send([//apartments])
});

router.get('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  return res.send({//apartment})
});
```

And so on with students or whatever.

This way, Angular is free to use it's own routes while the API runs under the /api/...

Answer (score 0):

You can set routes dynamically from angular, here is an example:

create routes handler:

```
var handler = function (req, res) {
    res.render('view');
}
```

add routes dynamically by calling `/addRouteDynamically/path`:

```
app.get('/addRouteDynamically/:path', function (req, res, next) {

     var path = req.params.path;

     app.get(path , handler);

});
```

Now if you call for example `GET /addRouteDynamically/appartement%2F%3Aid`, express will define new route handled by `handler` method

note that `appartement%2F%3Aid` is equivalent to `appartement/:id`

Answer (score 0):

**Angular 14 and Express**

Looks like I am late from the party, but I had the same issue and I searched a lot how can I solve this.

I am using Express to serve Angular and when I tried to use wildcard routing I ended up with blank page with Cannot GET error when I used a non-existing route on Angular side.

**The short answer:** Exclude index.html from Express static files

**The long answer:**

Express documentation about excluding files from static content: https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#path-examples

Stackoverflow about excluding files: [Exclude sub directory from static files in express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28680738/exclude-sub-directory-from-static-files-in-express)

You need to use Regex to exclude one file or certain files.

In your app.js, exclude all .html files from the static folder, so the wildcard routing could work:

```
app.use(['/(.*).html$/', '/'], express.static(path.join(__dirname, appPath)));
```

You can also just exclude the index.html with Regex, I excluded ALL the files which end with .html.

I also have a /api route on Express side and I had to put the excluding code BEFORE the the /api.